# Open a div in new window - on-click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Guys I am trying to open a div in new window and I tried with `window.open` ,its working as expected.

HTML:

```
<div id="pass">pass this to the new window</div>
<a href="#" onclick="openWin()">click</a>
```

JS:

```
  function openWin() {
    var divText = document.getElementById("pass").outerHTML;
    var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=200,height=100');
    var doc = myWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(divText);
    doc.close();
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KZYJU/

**Issue** : If the window is already opened, when I click the button again, it should not open a new window again.
User should be able to see only one window.
In my case if I click the button 10 times ,10 windows is getting opened.

Guys please assist me on this.

Comment: To create a [mcve], the code should be in the question. If that fiddle is deleted, this question stands useless. (Stack snippet isn't working for this code but you might want to read: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
  var popup;

  function openWin() {
    if (popup && !popup.closed) {
      popup.focus();
      /* or do something else, e.g. close the popup or alert a warning */
    } else {
      var divText = document.getElementById("pass").outerHTML;
      popup = window.open('', '', 'width=200,height=100');
      var doc = popup.document;
      doc.open();
      doc.write(divText);
      doc.close();
    }
  }
```

This will check if the popup window is open or not, and if it is then it will focus it.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ct6buw8o/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just play with the `Boolean` flag. make it true when you click it first time. and restrict it with that.

```js
var flag = false;
function openWin() {
  if(!flag) {
      var divText = document.getElementById("pass").outerHTML;
      var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=200,height=100');
      var doc = myWindow.document;
      doc.open();
      doc.write(divText);
      doc.close();
      flag = true
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="pass">pass this to the new window</div>
<a href="#" onclick="openWin()">click</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can write some script into the new window, you could use cookies to store a flag-like data in it so that you know the window is currently open.

On the main page, you first set the flag (I will name it windowOpen) to false, and check every time the link is clicked. If it is false then open new window; otherwise, do nothing.

On the subsequent window, set the flag to true on open and set it to false on close.

Answer (score 1):

Set a window name in your call to `window.open`

`window.open('', 'popupWindowName', 'width=200,height=100');`

> windowName is a DOMString specifying the name of the browsing context (window,  or tab) into which to load the specified resource; if the name doesn't indicate an existing context, a new window is created and is given the name specified by windowName. This name can then be used as the target of links and forms by specifying it as the target attribute of  or  elements. The name should not contain whitespace. Keep in mind that this will not be used as the window's displayed title.
>   If the string is empty, the browser will create a new window every time (this behaviour doesn't work when the string is replaced with NULL).

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: window is getting refreshed for each click.Is there any to open the window from where I left?